# Separate brokers for consumer and producer in Kafka using spring cloud stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have successfully implemented spring cloud stream and streaming using kafka.
I am consuming and then publishing to a destination topic.

All is working fine but I want to separate the brokers for my producer and consumer.
Current the properties are such that it reads from the same broker.

How to separate it ?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
    function:
      definition: RiskProcessor1;RiskProcessor2;RiskProcessor3;RiskProcessor4;RiskProcessor5
    stream:
      bindings:
        RiskProcessor1-in-0:
          destination: ******
        RiskProcessor1-out-0:
          destination: *****
        RiskProcessor2-in-0:
          destination: *****
        RiskProcessor2-out-0:
          destination: *****
        RiskProcessor3-in-0:
          destination: *****
        RiskProcessor3-out-0:
          destination: *****
        RiskProcessor4-in-0:
          destination: *****
        RiskProcessor4-out-0:
          destination: *****
        RiskProcessor5-in-0:
          destination: *****
        RiskProcessor5-out-0:
          destination: *****
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: kaas-int.nam.nsroot.net:9093
            functions:
              RiskProcessor1:
                applicationId: RiskProcessor1_development
              RiskProcessor2:
                applicationId: RiskProcessor2_development
              RiskProcessor3:
                applicationId: RiskProcessor3_development
              RiskProcessor4:
                applicationId: RiskProcessor4_development
              RiskProcessor5:
                applicationId: RiskProcessor5_development
            configuration:
              commit.interval.ms: 1000
              security.protocol: SSL
              default:
                deserialization:
                  exception:
                    handler: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
              schema:
                registry:
                  url: *****:9081
          default:
            consumer:
              keySerde: ****
              valueSerde: ****
            producer:
              keySerde: ****
              valueSerde: ****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd add more partitions to your topic(s).

Kafka determines leaders of partitions based on its internal algorithms. Leaders can be other brokers of the same cluster. Clients do not have direct control over this, outside of defining a partitioner interface for where messages are delivered

Comment: Can you clarify please ? Did not understand completely

Comment: Producers pick partitions. Partitions are hosted by brokers of one cluster. Unique partitions are not guaranteed to be on unique brokers. You cannot pick brokers, and one app cannot use multiple clusters for one bootstrap server config

Comment: Okay so in KStreams as in above example I posted, it is not possible as you said ?
If I confused you, the above example is KafkaStreams where I read from topic and publish to another topic. I just want to know if there is a possibility to read from a particular topic from 1 cluster and write to another topic on some other cluster in KStreams inJava

We can't have separate broker to consume and separate to produce [Both brokers are in diff cluster]?
kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: ***.nsroot.net:9093

Comment: For terminology, brokers defined by your bootstrap-server config must all be "one cluster". And no. Kafka Streams can only read and write topics of one cluster. You'd use tools like MirrorMaker2 to copy data to another cluster. Or use other frameworks than Kafka Streams like Spark or Flink to write to several clusters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for insights sir. This clears doubts.
Once question I have is to make SpringCloudStream using KStreams fasters, we have concurrency property. Also, we should have same partitions as total instances, my question is that should partitions be same in input topic and output topic for optimal performance ? Or output topic can have less partitions ?

Comment: I believe that's answered in the KStreams documentation itself. Partition count must be equal for stateful operations, I believe, otherwise, an internal repartition topic will be created, and this will cause less total throughput as data is shuffled between more than one topic

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
May I please request you to answer this question as well as you are well versed with this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77754921/kstreams-is-running-very-slow-in-spring-cloud-stream